# Git installation error "E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate" Ubuntu 16.04.6

Tags: 16.04, git

I checked the other posts for solutions, but am still facing this issue. I have updated Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt update`. But I'm still facing this issue, as follows:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
```

Can someone let me know how to solve this?
I am new to Ubuntu.

**Update**
I reinstalled ubuntu, and git got installed but now ubuntu isn't getting updated and giving the following error on runnung the command `sudo apt update`:

`E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`

Comment: `git` is there (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=git) so it could be your sources.list files have issue (eg. aren't complete), point to an outdated source, or there were messages in your `apt update` (or `apt-get update`; no need to run both) that you ignored (including lack of messages which would have been clue to problem).

Comment: I had similar issue with update and I read a post here which asked to update the sources.list file. I followed the steps and it got successfully updated. But I still had this issue for git.

Comment: The link I provided shows the package, the `apt update` should show a line that reflects the necessary repository line reflected in that link (we cannot read what you see on executing commands unless you provide it), but I'm betting the information was on your screen (or missing from your `apt update` output which is also a clue).  The alternative is you're behind a proxy (where I'd expect `apt update` output to gives your clues again).

Comment: So I reinstalled Ubuntu. Git got successfully installed but the update isn't working now. It shows the following error.  

E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/ca.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: Please add additional information to your question, (ideally command & output) as comments are hard to read (little formatting options, etc); you can edit your own questions and even if you don't get formatting correct in questions, others can help you (comments can only be deleted).

Comment: I've updated the question.